# how i can use Eval() as parameter in aspx file with ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

i have datasource control and listView control

the datasource have

> "StudentID,StudentName , Birthday ,Gander(M,F),Course_ID"

i want to display in my listView

> ("Age -> not BirthDay,Gander(male, female)->not f or' m, And
>   CourseName -> not courseID :))

i write some methods for do this work like this

```
    public  string CalculateAge(DateTime birthDate)
      {
            // cache the current time
            DateTime now = DateTime.Today; // today is fine, don't need the timestamp from now
            // get the difference in years
            int years = now.Year - birthDate.Year;
            // subtract another year if we're before the
            // birth day in the current year
            if (now.Month < birthDate.Month || (now.Month == birthDate.Month && now.Day < birthDate.Day))
                 --years;

            return years.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
      }
```

**but how i can use this methods in my aspx file with `Eval()` in my `ListView`? Note: I wrote this method in a different namespace**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have a problem using this in a `ListView`. Something like this should work:

```
<%# CalculateAge((DateTime)Eval("SomeDate")) %>
```

If this function is contained within a library that implements `IDisposable`, you can create a pass-through function in the code-behind:

```
public string CalculateAge(DateTime birthDate)
{
    using (var obj = new MyObject())
    {
        return obj.CalculateAge(birthDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks james but what about if my method in different namespace

Comment: Is that namespace accessible to the page? Can you access it from code-behind?

Comment: I think you can specify the full qualified name, i.e. `MyApp.Foo.MyFunction()`

Comment: thanks but not work >> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'CalculateAge' does not exist in the current context

Comment: That would indicate that the function is not accessible to the page. Did you import the namespace in the code-behind?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you're using it in the code-behind?

Comment: I mean i use "using statement"  using QStudent.Models; in my file "Manage.aspx.css"

Comment: If you're using it within a using statement, it's getting destroyed immediately after. You'll probably need to create a pass-through method in the code-behind.

Comment: i'm so sorry but what is pass-through method plz give me a link